# Drawing Straight Lines with Pen Tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes, path, pen-tool

I have just installed photoshop and  have, as an exercise , tried to design this logo.

[image]

I am stuck at trying to make one of those 8 rounded triangle shapes.I have used the pen tool to draw the upper arc but wen I try to sketch a line to the third vertex, I get a curve instead.I have tried changing from smooth point to corner point but that also converts the arc into a line.Is my approach correct? If so, how can I draw a straight line starting from a smooth point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, here's another way to create a triangle with one curved side, using the polygon tool and pen tool in Photoshop.

1-using the polygon tool, create an object with 3 sides
2-Rotate using Image > Image Rotation > 90 degrees Clockwise. Drag a vertical guide rule to align with the bottom triangle point (this helps define the triangle's vertical center). With the triangle selected and using the Pen Tool, click once to add an anchor point centered (highlighted with blue circle, below) between the top two triangle points.
3-Using the Direct Selection Tool, Shift+click and drag the new anchor point down to create the curve (holding Shift as you drag helps keep the point vertically centered). Shift+click on the bottom anchor point and adjust its position down (or up).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WJj6iNr6K0) and all your (or most of) your problems with Pen Tool. It's a really powerful tool but requires some practice and time to master it. Have fun! Hope this helps.

Comment: I have gone watched this .Tank you for the quick reply.I ave really understood how to make selections wit the pen tool, but drawing still remains a problem.I have found this tutorial but it also doesn't clearly elaborate as to how the basic shape is made.


http://designstacks.net/umbrella-corporation-logo

Answer (score 0):

i made it with the regular pen tool all you need to make is to make a new layer over the image

the lower the opacity of the new layer

the choose the pen tool and make sure that it has been set for a " shape " not a path

then start from the corner of any straight line then move towards the next corner ..

when you want to close the shape and make the rounded curved line you just hold and drag the line to match the image below ..

because the reason of the low opacity is that you can see how identical the two shapes are ...  [image]

after you make one shape just keep duplicating it ( ctrl + j ) and rotate it with the right angels of the shapes ..

then make any blinding options you want

Comment: I started with the shape tool but it drew weird curves.Could you kindly be a little more specific?